# allowing examination?

Tags: grammar

Source: Moorfields Manual of Ophthalmology

> Chemosis has reduced allowing examination of the cornea and intraocular structures.

What does "allowing" refers to? Or how else can we write this sentence?

Comment: I suspect you need to go to a medical site to get a reliable answer. The words quoted are not grammatical English.

Comment: @JeffMorrow chemosis is swelling of the eye often related to allergies or an eye infection. When it is severe, the cornea and intraocular structures cannot be examined until it 'reduces'. Looks like part of a longer sentence and there may be a preceding 'until'.

Comment: You could replace 'allowing' with 'permitting'.

Comment: @JeffMorrow It makes sense to me if I read it with a comma after "reduced".

Answer (score 6):

The sentence structure would be clearer with a comma after "reduced". The meaning of the sentence is:

- Chemosis has reduced (i.e. swelling has gone down);
- because chemosis has reduced, it is possible to examine the cornea and intraocular structures.

Here are some ways to rewrite the second part of the sentence (many others are also possible):

(1) Chemosis has reduced, permitting examination of the cornea and intraocular structures;

(2) Chemosis has reduced, making it possible to examine the cornea and intraocular structures;

(3) Chemosis has reduced, making examination of the cornea and intraocular structures possible.

(4) Chemosis has reduced, and as a result the cornea and intraocular structures can be examined.

Comment: Could we also write this sentence as : as a result of / because chemosis has reduced, examination of the cornea and intraocular structures has been allowed. ? yes slightly different in meaning. i noticed it. but isn't it a grammatically correct ? i was wondering about this ?

Comment: @emilywenly I wouldn't want to use the word 'allowed'.

Comment: The sentence "Because chemosis has reduced, examination of the cornea and intraocular structures has been allowed" is grammatical. However, it gives the impression that the examination has been "allowed" by some person (who has made a decision to allow it because of the reduction in chemosis).